# How to use generics and Any.Type with functions in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I'd like to keep a dictionary of keys of Enum Type and values that are managed by the Box type. But when I try to pass the key/value of each element in the dictionary to a function, I keep getting swift compiler errors on type mismatch.

I have Box declared as this:

```
final class Box<T> {
    let value: T

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

My dictionary:

```
let dictionary = [Car.Nissan: Box(value: NissanHandler.Type),
                  Car.Honda: Box(value: HondaHandler.Type), 
                  ...]
```

NissanHandler and HondaHandler are both classes which inherit from a protocol named 'AutoHandler'.

As I enumerate through each key/value in the dictionary, I'd like to pass each element off to another function to process it:

```
Class A {
  func processDictionary() {
    for (key, values) in dictionary {     
        // This line produces the error, 
        // Cannot convert value of type 'Box<CarHandler.Type>' to expected argument type '[Product : Box<Any.Type>]'
        processElement(key, value) 
    }
  }

  func processElement(key: Product, value: Box<Any.Type>) {
        // Instantiate the class based on the value's class type
  }    
}
```

How should I declare my function so I can keep the mapping of the classes that should be instantiated at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably for a way to "pass" generic placeholder down to the underlying box? If so, this code might help:

```
func processElement<K, V>(key: K, value: V) {

}
```

now if I understood correctly your class would look like this:

```
final class Box<T> {
    let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class A {
    let dictionary: [String: Box<Int>] = [
        "a": Box(2),
        "b": Box(4)
    ]

    func processDictionary() {
        dictionary.forEach(process)
    }

    func process<K, V>(key: K, box: Box<V>) {
        print(key, box.value)
        // a, 2
        // b, 4
    }
}
```

Note, that `forEach(function)` is a shortcut to `dictionary.forEach{ k, v in function(k, v)}` and is a shorter way to iterate over key, value calling a function on each of them

As for `Any` type, to be honest I don't remember when was the last time I used it, usually there is a better way and you always want to provide as much of type information as possible